# Reactive programming (Reactor) : Why main thread is stuck?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm learning Reactive programming with project-reactor.

I have the following test case:

```
@Test
public void createAFlux_just() {
    Flux<String> fruitFlux = Flux.just("apple", "orange");
    fruitFlux.subscribe(f -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(f);
    });
    System.out.println("hello main thread");
}
```

By executing the test it seems that the main thread is stuck for 5 seconds.

I would expect that the subscribed consumer should run asynchronously in its own thread, that is, the subscribe invoke should return immediately to the main thread and consequently the `hello main thread` should print instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thread is stuck because the subscription happens on the `main` thread. If you want it to run asynchronously, you need to the subscription to happen on a thread other than `main`. You could do this as:

```
 @Test
public void createAFlux_just() {
    Flux<String> fruitFlux = Flux.just("apple", "orange");
    fruitFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe(f -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(f);
    });
    System.out.println("hello main thread");
}
```

Note: I have used the `parallel` thread pool. You could use whatever pool you like. Reactor's pipelines are executed on the calling thread by default (unlike `CompletableFuture<T>` which runs in the `ForkJoin` pool by default).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior would be the case if you had an observable (Flux) that was asynchronous. You chose to use a Flux with two readily available values by using the just method. They were passed to the subscription object right away since they were immediately available.

Answer (score 1):

from spring.io [documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers)

> **The Threading Model**
> Reactor operators generally are concurrent agnostic: they don’t impose a particular threading model and just run on the Thread on which their onNext method was invoked.
>
> **The Scheduler abstraction**
> In Reactor, a Scheduler is an abstraction that gives the user control about threading. A Scheduler can spawn Worker which are conceptually Threads, but are not necessarily backed by a Thread (we’ll see an example of that later). A Scheduler also includes the notion of a clock, whereas the Worker is purely about scheduling tasks.

so you should subscribe on different thread by `subscribeOn` method and the `Thread.sleep(5000)` will sleep thread of the scheduler. You can see more examples like this one in the documentation.

```
Flux.just("hello")
    .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("just " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
    .publishOn(Scheduler.boundedElastic())
    .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("publish " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v + " delayed " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```